# Restarting a do loop

Tags: for-loop, fortran, fortran90, restart

i have a do loop that goes from 1 to n which contains an if statement.
And if the requirement is met, certain parameters , including the n have changed.
So i would then like to start the entire do loop again from i=1 until i=n until the requirement is no longer met and and i reaches n.
But i am not sure how to program this in fortran.
Because in the current situation, where the do loop continues after the if statement, if the if statement is then met for another i, it will overwrite the previous data. And if the do-loop will restart each time the requirement is met, this is no longer the case.
Does someone know how to program this in fortran 90?

So there is an array that contains a column of numbers. In case the if-statement is met i want to insert an extra number into the column. So all numbers before that point should remain in place, all points after this extra point should move one down, and then in the free spot that is created, the extra point comes. This all works fine.
However if the if-statement is met twice, two points have to be added, but at the time the second point has to be added, it will overwrite the data from adding the first point. So if it is possible to completely restart the if-loop from scratch starting with the result from the first time, including the extra point, it will work.
**So it should start at i=1 then keep going until the if-statement is met, execute the if-statement, start again at i=1, and repeat this until i=n (which increases each time a point is added)**
I dont see how the code is relevant, but especially for you:
prevnumbers is the starting numbers, which followed some steps which resulted in numbers. If then numbers does not meet the if statement, the original numbers (prevnumbers) have to be changed and then the steps are done again.

```
do i = 1,n
    if (numbers(i,1) >= x) then
    !this part will transfer the previous numbers to the new numbers until the new point
        do j=1,i
            numbers(j,1)=prevnumbers(j,1)
        end do
        !This part will move the numbers after the new number one ahead so a free spot is created
        do j=n,i,-1
            numbers(j+1,1)=prevnumbers(j,1)
        end do
        !this part adds the new number and increases n by 1.
        numbers(i+1,1)=(prevnumbers(i,1)+prevnumbers(i+1,1))/2
        n=n+1
    end if
end do
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: If you do not know the exact number of iterations beforehand you probably shouldn't use a do loop with an index in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know the exact number of iterations beforehand you probably shouldn't use a do loop with an index in the first place. Not tested.

```
i = 0
do
   i = i + 1
   if (i>n) exit

    if (numbers(i,1) >= x) then
    !this part will transfer the previous numbers to the new numbers until the new point
        do j=1,i
            numbers(j,1)=prevnumbers(j,1)
        end do
        !This part will move the numbers after the new number one ahead so a free spot is created
        do j=n,i,-1
            numbers(j+1,1)=prevnumbers(j,1)
        end do
        !this part adds the new number and increases n by 1.
        numbers(i+1,1)=(prevnumbers(i,1)+prevnumbers(i+1,1))/2
        n=n+1
    end if
end do
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is not appropriate for your problem, use a do-while loop.

```
i=1
do while(i<=n)
  ! if the condition is met
  ! do all the stuff
  ! set the new value of n
  ! set i to 1 to restart the loop
end do
```

Make sure that you don't loop forever, meaning that at some point i goes from 1 to n without the condition being met.